# Is there a term among heavy computer users for a cat who treads on the keyboard to highly deleterious effect?

Tags: phrase-requests, computing

The question line pretty much says it all. I'm not asking why, or how to stop it.  I am asking if this behavior has generated a term or phrase amongst cat-loving heavy computer users.

From the comments and the two answers, it seems that cats on keyboards (piano and computer) are well known, but that there is no widely accepted term or phrase for the havoc they can wreak.  Correct?

Comment: Don't recall anything specific, thought there are occasional complaints that "the cat must have typed that" when something gets screwed up.  And a few decades back it was common for people to come up with humorous lists of "trouble codes" and the like, such as PEBCAK "Problem exists between chair and keyboard".

Comment: You can protest yourself against it http://bitboost.com/pawsense/

Comment: Hot - excellent point on the common riposte *""the cat must have typed that"*

Comment: Damn. That's not really a riposte.  I hate when I use the wrong word  :/  :/

Comment: MGB: Just goes to show ya..... no matter what it is, there's an app for that!   (btw "protect", not "protest")

Comment: Warning! Cat-like typing detected.

Comment: And for the *opposite* of a deleterious effect, on a musical keyboard: Scarlatti's "Cat Fugue": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRZtLjfM9V4.  Scarlatti got the motif from writing down the notes heard when his cat took a little walk on his keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really terribly clever one would be

## "fat-paw"

If you don't get it, check out trader's lingo (I mean, stock-market traders).

Comment: Please, do **not** try to edit questions/anwsers that are anyway quite lighthearted overall.  Sure, the whole QA should just be deleted since it's off topic; it is pointless making arcane edits to others bits.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I nominate "Kitten on the Keys," after the 1921 ragtime hit by  American composer Edward Elzear "Zez" Confrey.  You may listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEBokfAeCnM) as you contemplate actual feline computer keyboarding, like the original "[Keyboard Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_Cat)" (since promoted to a meme) or perhaps this more [relaxed style](http://allthecreatures.org/humor/cats-will-be-kittens.html).

Comment: impressive ... most impressive.  (FTR another masterpiece on the same topic .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khvaIwonxUk )